# hiberfil.sys и ОЗУ

Tags: windows, hdd, восстановление

Нажала пуск-->гибернация. Компьютер ушел в гибернацию соответственно.
Потом включила на следующий день.

Вопрос.

1. После включения в файл hiberfil.sys записалось что-либо?
   Или файл hiberfil.sys остаётся не именным, до следующей гибернации?
2. Существует ли софт, который может извлечь данные из hiberfil.sys?

Comment: 1: туда же перед выключением пишется, а после включения только читается. 
2: https://diverto.github.io/2019/11/05/Extracting-Passwords-from-hiberfil-and-memdumps
3: что такое Тэшкирешики?

Comment: Конечно существует софт. Как минимум сама операционная система. Она же именно **извлекает** оттуда данные.

Comment: @Pavel Gridin , 1. возможно ли ещё раз запустить(повторно) туже гибернацию?
2. после пробуждения(компьютера), и отработки файла гибернации.. можно ли извлечь данные из файла hiberfil.sys?
3. имя.

Comment: [Похоже вы случайно создали две учётные записи, посмотрите как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)